# Creating a auto-populated population spreadsheet file in Google Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-workspace, spreadsheet

Not sure if this is the proper place to post this, but worth worth a try. I am using Google Sheets to create a series of files for worldbuilding for a bunch of stories. What I am trying to do is have a sheet of a local population organized by year. The sheet includes several variables for growth rate as well as additional population entries. The part of this that is world-building is that I have the population for several future star-systems. It's overkill I know, but overkill is under rated.

The attempt: In another sheet/tab, I have a journey log. This sheet includes the time a colony ship leaves from a certain system, the duration of the trip, the time upon arrival, and lastly the population aboard the ship at arrival as these are generation ships so they typically increase about ten-fold. I have even done simple calculations to show the relative time experienced by those onboard due to time dilation...Overkill I know. **What I am trying to accomplish is to have the starting population subtracted from the departure location's population on the year of departure, and then the new arrival population added to the destination's population on the year of arrival.**

My limitations are I need to do this in 1 row and I would like to not have to do several stages of  formula filled cells that stretch all the way to to a ZZ column. There will be several entries that leave from the same place on the same year and vice versa, so I am assuming I could use some form of Lookup or index-Match. I tried playing around with it for sometime but I had to give up as I was going in circles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "It's overkill I know, but overkill is under rated." - This is perhaps my favourite quote this year from our community.  Thank you for the smile. :)

Comment: Are you looking for software to accomplish this task, or help with existing software?  The former is on-topic for our community, but the latter is not.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Glad I could make someone smile! The question is geared towards getting a formula/setup to work in Google Sheets for this, or even excel.

Comment: Thank you again for the smile! Always appreciated! Unfortunately, getting this to work in known software will be off-topic for our community. It is probably on-topic for Super User.  Would you like me to see if I can migrate it there?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on webapps

Comment: Perhaps you can share some screenshots of your spreadsheets so that we can better understand the task. Having said that, if your growth rates are constant, then financial formulas (FV and PV) may work for you, just think people instead of money.